# ConfigMap with an array of objects

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

friends, i'm writing a k8s configmap with a array of objects, but it doesn't convert to json in my .Net app

my JSON example

`

```
"ApiServices":[
  "Api1": {
     "CircuitBreakerConfiguration":{anything},
     "FallbackConfiguration":{anything}   
       },
  "Api2": {
     "CircuitBreakerConfiguration":{anything},
     "FallbackConfiguration":{anything}
   }
 ]
```

what can i do now?

i try this but doesnt work

`

```
           - Name: "Api1"
             Endpoint: ""
             PolicyConfiguration:
               RetryConfiguration:
                 RetryCount: 2
                 TimeoutInMilliseconds: 1000
           - Name: "Api2"
             Endpoint: ""
             HeaderPropagation: false
             PolicyConfiguration:
               CircuitBreakerConfiguration:
                 HandledEventsAllowedBeforeBreaking: 3
                 DurationOfBreakInMilliseconds: 100000
               RetryConfiguration:
                 RetryCount: 1
                 TimeoutInMilliseconds: 3000
```

Comment: What does your ConfigMap look like?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.